# Get the next number greater than a number from a row matching another number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this table in Excel

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F
  __________________
1 | X  1  5 10     Y
2 | Y  2  4  9     5
3 | Z  3  7  8
```

I want to be able to input a character (or number) from column A and a number and have a formula that outputs the next number equal to or greater than the inputed number from a row matching the inputed character.

Example: In the table the inputed character, Y, and number, 5, should result in 9, which is the next number greater than 5 from row 2.

I've been trying to find a combination of Index and Match but haven't been able to get it to work. I'm guessing it should look a little something like this:

```
INDEX(B:D;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(B:D;MATCH(F1;A:A;0);0)>=F2;0))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your numbers in ascending order from left to right? It may be possible to make use of this if so?

Comment: Yes they are. They're pipe wall thicknesses and the first column is the DN number of the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$D$3/(($A$1:$A$3=F1)*($B$1:$D$3>=F2)), 1) 'Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This one works but it's too resource heavy. I have a table that's a bit bigger than the one in the example and I need to calculate this around one hundred times. I get an error message about Excel running out of resources while calculating after just a few rows of calculations. Can you perhaps think of someting more light weight? :)

Comment: @KáriRafnKarlsson if you want a single formula that's the best I can think about. Alternative should be to use helper columns, one that finds the "Y" row and another that indexes in that row. You can also use a VBA loop, but that will be much slower, albeit less memory consuming.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I did manage to get it working better by clearly defining the range, instead of using columns alone.

Comment: @KáriRafnKarlsson oh, I see, it surely should make it faster and reduce  memory usage. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a purely INDEX/MATCH version of this which is still fast on whole columns

```
=IFERROR(IF(F2<INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),1),INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),1),IF(INDEX(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),0),MATCH(F2,INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),0)))=F2,INDEX(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),0),MATCH(F2,INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),0))),INDEX(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),0),MATCH(F2,INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),0))+1))),"No match")
```

Method

(1) Locate and extract the matching row from B:D.

(2) If F2 is less than the first element of the row, set the result equal to the first element.

(3) Using the non-exact form of MATCH, find which is the last value less than or equal to F2 (i.e. 4 in the example).

(4) If this is equal to F2, give it as the result

(5) If not, give the next value as the result (i.e. 9 in the example).

If F2 is greater than the last element of the row, it will give "No match".